# Concatenar cadenas en C++

Tags: c++, string

estoy haciendo un ejercicio que te pide escribir tu nombre y en el que se tiene que imprimir la frase "Hola qué tal" más el nombre que escribiste utilizando cadenas. El programa funciona, sin embargo el nombre sale junto, entonces ¿qué hago para que salga separado?

```
/* Ejercicio 4 cadenas*/
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char cadena[] = "Hola que tal";
char nombre[100];

 cout<<" Escribe tu nombre "; cin.getline(nombre,100,'\n');

  strcat(cadena,nombre);

cout<<" Frase : "<< cadena <<endl;






    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me creo que nadie pregunte esto. ¿ Es un programa de cámara oculta o algo ?

Comment: @Trauma, sólo es una duda, por eso se creo este espacio, además está un poco fuera  de lugar tu comentario

Answer (score 2):

Agregá un espacio al final de la `cadena`:

```
char cadena[] = "Hola que tal ";
```

Comment: gracias, funciona

Answer (score 1):

Además de que puedes resolverlo agregando un espacio a la  cadena, `string.h` es una librería de C.

Lo ideal sería que uses la librería [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

El código te quedaría algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string cadena = "Hola que tal ";
    string nombre;

    cout << " Escribe tu nombre ";
    cin >> nombre;

    cadena += nombre;

    cout << " Frase: " << cadena << "\n";
}
```

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia